# Which regular expression engine (flavor) does "Some Package" use?

Tags: regex

Unfortunately, the regex section of many manuals starts with a tutorial, and often leaves this question unanswered. If the answer for the package that brought you to this page is not below, please add it, in a direct and short format, with links if applicable.

Comment: See also http://www.regular-expressions.info/tools.html

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_regular_expression_engines has a table with fairly good coverage of popular tools (and some markedly less so).

Comment: @tripleee: I added a column "Used by" to the Wikipedia page you mentioned, and it seems to have stuck (i.e., it has not been deleted by an editor). Would you be so kind as to add an answer summarizing your comments and pointers above and pointing to that table? Then I'll change the question if necessary, i.e., remove the "add below" clause, and mark your answer correct. Hopefully people will add the information to that table.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP Regex flavors

```
1.) PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expressions)
    preg* functions
    PHP: PCRE - Manual, PCRE man pages, perlre

2.) POSIX ERE (Extended Regular Expressions)
    ereg* functions -> DEPRECATED
    PHP: ereg - Manual, man pages

3.) POSIX ERE with multibyte support
    mb_ereg* functions
    PHP: mb_ereg - Manual
```

Feel free to add further information.

Answer (score 0):

[Kate](http://www.kate-editor.org/doc/regular-expressions.html), and thus Kile, use [the QRegExp class](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qregexp.html), which [is PCRE-like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12327032/), but not quite [PCRE](http://www.pcre.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Nginx uses [PCRE](http://www.pcre.org/). For more information, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14126872/).

Answer (score 0):

Jedit uses [java.util.regex from 4.3, and gnu.regexp before that](http://www.jedit.org/users-guide/regexps.html).